# Passing non-default arguments to Tk class constructor

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to pass two Queues objects to a class the inherits Tk.tk.

main.py code:

```
qin = Queue()
qout = Queue()

gui = GUI(qin,qout)
gui.mainloop()
```

gui.py code:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) #if im calling tk.Tk.__init__(self) nothing is displayed to the screen so *args, **kwargs is requirement for some reason, not sure why

        self.qin = args[0]
        self.qout = args[1]

    ...
```

error:

```
    gui = GUI(qin,qout)
  File "/home/a/gui.py", line 20, in __init__
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not Queue
```

How to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is `Queue()`? Is this from a library. If so where are you imports?
It is harder to trouble shoot without enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just pop the args off of kwargs before passing kwargs to the superclass init.

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qin = kwargs.pop("qin", None)
        qout = kwargs.pop("qout", None)
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or, if you don't care about the caller being able to pass in other arguments through to the superlcass, just define them as normal arguments:

```
 class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, qin, qout):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```